# Typeahead.js not working on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, heroku, meteor, typeahead.js

I was able to get the typeahead.js plugin working on my dev machine, but once I pushed my code to heroku it stopped working. Here's the relevant code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  window.onload = function() {
    $("input.entry").typeahead({
     name: "movies",
     remote: {
      url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=####################&page_limit=5&q=%QUERY",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      template: ["<p><strong>{{title}}</strong></p>"],
      engine: Handlebars,
      filter: function(parsedResponse) {
        var dataset = [];
        movies = parsedResponse.movies;
        for(i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
          dataset.push({
              value: movies[i].title,
              details: movies[i].critics_consensus,
              image: movies[i].posters.profile
          });
        }
        return dataset;
      }
    }
  });

  $('input.entry').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum) {
    Movies.insert({
      name: datum.value,
      consensus: datum.details,
      image: datum.image,
      voters: [],
      creator: Meteor.user(),
      time: Date.now()
    });
  });
}
```

If I paste the contents of `window.onload` into the javascript console after the page loads it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your app on `http://api.rottentomatoes.com`? Otherwise you'll have CORS issues.

Comment: Yes, I have created an app on the rotten tomatoes developer site

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by putting the typeahead.js code in this block `Template.entryfield.rendered = function () { ... }`